# How to add nonce & state to OpenID based Named Credential

Tags: namedcredentials, open-id-connect

I'm working on an integration using a named credential with an OpenID auth. provider. I'm getting a `nonce_is_missing` response when running the authentication flow (during save of the named credential). Is there any way to add a nonce and a state to the initial authentication request?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There is no code to share.. To reproduce; create an OpenID Auth. Provider and a related Named Credential to a service that requires a nonce and observe that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious solution was the correct one; you can just add GET parameters to the Authorize Endpoint URL... It's not really a random nonce anymore, but at least in my situtation this did the trick: https://[some-app]/auth/authentication/connect/authorize?nonce=12345

Comment: yeah that's what I did too. But ideally there should be a way Salesforce can generate a random nonce for us ...